# PL-SQL Delete item from a table of Objects

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to delete an item from a variable of type table of objects:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST"  IS TABLE OF o_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST" IS OBJECT (
    WizAttrEditID           NUMBER,
    InternalIndex           NUMBER,
    DimensionObjectID       NUMBER,
    AttributeName           VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeLabel          VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeType           NUMBER,
    AttributeLength         VARCHAR2(50),
    MandatoryAttribute      NUMBER,
    ReadOnly                NUMBER,
    Name                    VARCHAR2(2000),
    Num                     NUMBER,
    IsModified              NUMBER,
    Colour                  NUMBER);
```

I'm itterating through the list of objects, I checked and the `ls_attr_list.COUNT` is 16 and I try to delete one item when a criteria is met but I get this error :

> ORA-01403: no data found

which is raised at this line : `ls_attr_list.Delete(i);`

```
FOR i IN 1..ls_attr_list.COUNT LOOP
           BEGIN
               IF ls_attr_list(i).attributename = 'PROTECTION_ROLE' THEN
                   ls_attr_list.Delete(i);
                END IF;
               EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
                 writelog(SQLERRM,'ERROR');
                 END;
            END LOOP;
```

the ls_attr_list is initialize with the input parameter:

```
PROCEDURE AttribInit(geninfo        IN OUT    o_geninfo,
                     pageinfo       IN OUT    o_attributepage_pageinfo,
                     attributelist  IN OUT    t_attributepage_attributelist,
                     enumlist       IN OUT    t_attributepage_enumlist)

AS
ls_attr_list := attributelist;
```

Problem when itterating over the list after deleting one item

```
i := attributelist.FIRST; 
LOOP 
IF attributelist(i).attributename = 'PROTECTION_ROLE' THEN attributelist.DELETE(i); 
END IF; 
EXIT WHEN i = attributelist.LAST; 
i := attributelist.NEXT(i);
 END LOOP; 
--second FOR
FOR i in 1..attributelist.COUNT LOOP
```

> --no data found when it reaches the index of the previous deleted item

```
writelog(attributelist(i).attributename,'attributename'); 
END LOOP;
```

I'm doing something wrong, any ideas what??

Comment: You might need to use `FIRST/LAST/NEXT` rather than using a `FOR` loop since `COUNT < LAST` when you have deleted values from the middle of a collection.

Comment: Don't know why but I tried this solution when I first saw the no data error and somehow it didn't work, but maybe beeing in a rush I made a mistake, Now seems to work, but I found a function that I'm using now that takes the list and the value to look for as a parameter and return the position an then I delete the item from the list, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
FOR i IN 1 .. ls_attr_list.COUNT LOOP
```

Will cause exceptions/errors when you have deleted an element from the collection. Each time you delete an element it creates a gap in the collection and the next time you try and run the procedure it will get to that gap and throw a `ORA-01403: no data found`.

Instead you need to loop between `i := ls_attr_list.FIRST` and `ls_attr_list.LAST` and use `i := ls_attr_list.NEXT(i)` to get the next index.

A simplified working example is:

```sql
CREATE TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
/
    
DECLARE
  vals VARCHAR2_Table := VARCHAR2_Table( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' );

  PROCEDURE del_Val (
    v IN OUT VARCHAR2_Table,
    x IN     VARCHAR2
  )
  AS
    idx     PLS_INTEGER;
  BEGIN
    IF v IS NULL OR v IS EMPTY THEN
      RETURN;
    END IF;
    idx := v.FIRST;
    LOOP
      EXIT WHEN idx IS NULL;
      IF v(idx) = x THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(idx);
        v.DELETE(idx);
      END IF;
      idx := v.NEXT(idx);
    END LOOP;
  END;

BEGIN
  del_Val( vals, 'b' );
  del_Val( vals, 'f' );
  del_Val( vals, 'a' );
END;
/
```

However using this procedure:

```sql
PROCEDURE del_Val (
  v IN OUT VARCHAR2_Table,
  x IN     VARCHAR2
)
AS
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. v.COUNT LOOP
    IF v(i) = x THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(i);
      v.DELETE(i);
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Would have caused `ORA-01403: no data found` when the procedure is called the second time.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b5e4ea55da42c67e1aa3c79010c60e45)*

Comment: most explicit answer, marked as the solution, thank you

Comment: @AndreiMaieras That's because you **cannot** use `FOR i IN t_tab.FIRST .. t_tab.LAST LOOP ... END LOOP;` to iterate over a sparse collection. You need to use `i := t_tab.FIRST; LOOP ... EXIT WHEN i = t_tab.LAST; i := t_tab.NEXT(i); END LOOP;` to do the iteration otherwise you will get exceptions as it will try to access the gaps in the sparse collection and fail.

Comment: Post another [MCVE] question with your code and the issues. Trying to ask it is comments is unreadable.

Comment: In such a basic case, why not use "vals := vals MULTISET EXCEPT <set of values to be removed>"? It's WAY more "compact".

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the scenario in a very lucid way hope this helps.

```
--Obj Creation
CREATE OR REPLACE type av_obj_test
IS
  object
  (
    col1 VARCHAR2(100),
    col2 VARCHAR2(100) );

--TABLE Type creation
CREATE OR REPLACE type av_ntt_test
IS
  TABLE OF av_obj_test;

--Anonymous block  
DECLARE
av_t av_ntt_test:=av_ntt_test(av_obj_test('av','roy'),av_obj_test('sh','roy'));
BEGIN
FOR I IN av_t.FIRST..av_t.LAST LOOP
IF av_t(i).col1 = 'av' THEN
av_t.DELETE(I);
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: This is not an attempt to answer the question - it is a simplified re-hash of the question and should be edit to the question or a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your not doing anything wrong. When you delete something, there is a gap which cause this error like @MT0 wrote. 
I play with Your code a little and:

```
  declare
  t_tab T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST;
  i number;
  begin
t_tab:= T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST ();
t_tab.EXTEND(9);
t_tab(1):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('asd',1);
t_tab(2):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('tyh',2);
t_tab(3):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('adgdfsd',3);
t_tab(4):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('fg',4);
t_tab(5):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('test',5);
t_tab(6):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('test',6);
t_tab(7):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('adaaaasd',7);
t_tab(8):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('qwwwww',8);
t_tab(9):=O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST('poikj',9);
i:=t_tab.FIRST;
LOOP
 dbms_output.put_line(t_tab(i).AttributeName||' '||t_tab(i).AttrNUMBER);

 if t_tab(i).AttributeName = 'test' then t_tab.delete(i);
 t_tab(i):=null;
 end if;


 EXIT when i=t_tab.LAST;
 i:=t_tab.NEXT(i);
 end loop;

 dbms_output.put_line('==============================================');
  for i IN t_tab.FIRST..t_tab.LAST LOOP

  if  t_tab(i) is null then
 continue;
  else
 dbms_output.put_line(t_tab(i).AttributeName||' '||t_tab(i).AttrNUMBER);
  end if;
 end loop;
  end;
    /
```

OUTPUT:

```
asd 1
tyh 2
adgdfsd 3
fg 4
test 5
test 6
adaaaasd 7
qwwwww 8
poikj 9
==============================================
asd 1
tyh 2
adgdfsd 3
fg 4
adaaaasd 7
qwwwww 8
poikj 9
```

after `t_tab.delete(i)` a gave  `t_tab(i):=null;` which eliminated gap, and compiler doesn't have any problems to iterate again over this collection and print all items (because there was no gap, there was something - NULL, and NULL is SOMETHING, Hope You will understand :) ). And like users above adivced - You should use FIRST..LAST instead of count.

Comment: In your example, the `t_tab.delete(i);` is completely superfluous and can be removed. You are calling `t_tab.delete(i);` then you immediately re-create the element with `t_tab(i):=null;` - a non-existent element and a `null` element are two entirely different things.

Comment: Did not I write it? that GAP (non-existent element) and null are diffrent things?

Comment: As I said, if you remove the `t_tab.delete(i);` statement from your example and the code will do exactly the same thing. You are (effectively) not doing a delete but a replacement with `NULL` and this will cause errors if the OP is relying on things like `t_tab.COUNT` (which will include `NULL` elements but not deleted elements) to know the size of the collection. It will also complicate all the logic as you now have to test whether each object in the collection is non-null.

Comment: No, I am saying you should **not** set anything to `NULL` but you should use `t_tab.DELETE(i);` and then use `FIRST/LAST/NEXT` to iterate the sparse collection properly - setting things to `NULL` is just creating more work using a temporary sticking plaster that you then need to work around.

Comment: When i did delete and try to print int next loop, in output i had only items from 1 to 4. 7,8,9 did not appear.
Sorry, by accident I remove last post.

Comment: That's because you **cannot** use `FOR i IN t_tab.FIRST .. t_tab.LAST LOOP ... END LOOP;` to iterate over a sparse collection. You need to use `i := t_tab.FIRST; LOOP ... EXIT WHEN i = t_tab.LAST; i := t_tab.NEXT(i); END LOOP;` otherwise you will get exceptions as it will try to access the gaps in the sparse collection and fail.

Comment: Daaamn, In 2nd loop i leave FIRST..LAST. I did changed only in 1st loop. Sorry, my mistake. Long day :)

Answer (score 0):

The below will handle even if the last element of the collection gets deleted

```
DECLARE
  TYPE VARCHAR2_TABLE IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20);
  vals VARCHAR2_Table := VARCHAR2_Table( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f' );
  PROCEDURE del_Val (
    v IN OUT VARCHAR2_Table,
    x IN     VARCHAR2
  )
  AS
    i INT;
    v_last_deleted boolean;
  BEGIN
    IF v IS NULL OR v IS EMPTY THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No more data');
      RETURN;
    END IF;
    i := v.FIRST;
    LOOP
      IF v(i) = x THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  -> Delting element at : '||i||' that has vaulue of :'||v(i));
        if (i = v.LAST) then v_last_deleted := true; end if;
        v.DELETE(i);
      ELSE 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('  --> Not Delting element at : '||i||' that has vaulue of :'||v(i));      
      END IF;
      EXIT WHEN v IS NULL OR v IS EMPTY OR v_last_deleted OR (i = v.LAST);
      i := v.NEXT(i);
    END LOOP;
  END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'b' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'e' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'a' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'a' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'f' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'c' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'd' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'a' );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Count : '||vals.count);
  del_Val( vals, 'b' );
END;
/
```

Comment: Why not use "vals := vals MULTISET EXCEPT <set of values to be removed>"? It's WAY more "compact".