# PL-SQL - Eliminate gaps from a table of objects

Tags: oracle, plsql

Having `T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST` as a table of objectes like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST"  IS TABLE OF o_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST" IS OBJECT (
    WizAttrEditID           NUMBER,
    InternalIndex           NUMBER,
    DimensionObjectID       NUMBER,
    AttributeName           VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeLabel          VARCHAR2(50),
    AttributeType           NUMBER,
    AttributeLength         VARCHAR2(50),
    MandatoryAttribute      NUMBER,
    ReadOnly                NUMBER,
    Name                    VARCHAR2(2000),
    Num                     NUMBER,
    IsModified              NUMBER,
    Colour                  NUMBER);
attributelist     t_attributepage_attributelist;
```

I'm deleting one item from the table:

```
attributelist.DELETE(ln_attrib_pos_function);
```

Then if I try to iterate through the list I have

> data not found

```
 FOR i in 1..attributelist.COUNT LOOP
      ...
      END LOOP;
```

I've tried also with `FIRST` and `LAST` methods but result is the same.
What I want is somehow make again the table dense so a subsequent iteration after deletion is possible without any error. I tried creating new table and eliminate the gap from initial table with the `EXISTS` method but I get

> subscription beyond count

This I think is because the loop skips the deleted item so the i index turns 
from 10 to 12 if the item deleted was at index 11

```
FOR i in 1..attributelist.COUNT LOOP
  IF attributelist.EXISTS(i) THEN
    ls_attribute_list.EXTEND;
    ls_attribute_list(i) := attributelist(i);
    ELSE
      CONTINUE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  attributelist := ls_attribute_list;
```

Basically I want the initial `attributelist` to be ready for iteration after I delete one or more items.

Comment: If you have 4 items in the list and delete the first one then `COUNT` will be reduced from `4` to `3` but the value of `LAST` stays a `4` - so if you loop from `1 .. list.COUNT` and test if the item exists you will miss the items from the end of the list which have an index greater than `COUNT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to accept that if you are going to delete from collections then they can be sparse and iterate over them using the `FIRST/LAST/NEXT` methods:

```
i := attributeList.FIRST;
LOOP
  -- do stuff
  EXIT WHEN i = attributeList.LAST;
  i := attributeList.NEXT(i);
END LOOP;
```

Yes, it is slightly more to type than `FOR i IN attributeList.FIRST .. attributeList.LAST LOOP ... do stuff ... END LOOP;` but not by much and your application logic will not suddenly start breaking in random places when you have forgotten to handle a delete called several procedures ago.

However, if you want to make a non-sparse copy of a sparse collection you can do:

```
CREATE FUNCTION compactCollection(
  list IN  T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST,
) RETURN T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST DETERMINISTIC
IS
BEGIN
  IF list IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;

  RETURN T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST()
           MULTISET UNION list;
END;
/
```

But it would be better just to use the proper iteration method for sparse collections.

**Update**

The [`MULTISET UNION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm) operator will concatenate two collections returning a new collection (of the same type as the operands). A side effect of the concatentation is that the resulting collection is dense.

So concatenating an empty collection with a sparse collection will result in a compacted (dense) version of the sparse collection.

```
attributeList := T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST() MULTISET UNION attributeList;
```

Will give the same elements (in the same order) but just compact the element indices.

*(If you want the code for a longer version using `FIRST/LAST/NEXT` iteration then see the [first edit of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/37744106/1))*

Comment: I agree with the approach of correct iteration but I'm adding this code into an existing procedure and if someone in the future is not use to this kind of iteration and tries to iterate over the list it will break, can't I just create a new array without the gap from the original one and then assign this auxiliar array back to the original one?

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
FOR i in attributelist.first..attributelist.last LOOP
```

If you delete in the middle `COUNT` reduces. `FIRST` and `LAST` and `EXISTS` is what you need.

EDIT: But to avoid looping over deleted entries you could do as MT0 suggested and use `NEXT`.

```
  i := attributelist.first; 
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line(attributelist(i).WizAttrEditID);
    exit when i = attributelist.last; 
    i := attributelist.next(i);
  END LOOP;
```

Testing it with the following Routine:

```
set serveroutput on 
declare
  attributelist      t_attributepage_attributelist;
  ls_attribute_list  t_attributepage_attributelist;
  i                  number;
begin
  attributelist := t_attributepage_attributelist();
  ls_attribute_list := t_attributepage_attributelist();
  attributelist.extend;
  attributelist(1) := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(1,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
  attributelist.extend;
  attributelist(2) := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(2,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
  attributelist.extend;
  attributelist(3) := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(3,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
  attributelist.extend;
  attributelist(4) := O_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST(4,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
  attributelist.delete(1);
  attributelist.delete(3);
  dbms_output.put_line('count='||attributelist.count||' last='||attributelist.last);
  i := attributelist.first; 
  LOOP
    exit when i is null; -- in case everything is deleted
    dbms_output.put_line(attributelist(i).WizAttrEditID);
    exit when i = attributelist.last; 
    i := attributelist.next(i);
  END LOOP;
end;
```

Output:

```
count=2 last=4
2
4
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: If you create a list with `n` items and delete the middle `n-2` items then using this method you will still iterate `n` times even though you only have 2 items (`FIRST` and `LAST`) in the list.

Comment: If `n` is small or not very sparse then it probably does not matter but if `n` is large and very sparse then you are asking it to loop repeatedly and do a lot of unnecessary checks. This delay for just one iteration is probably not too problematic but if this gets called frequently then you can easily refactor the code to eliminate the unnecessary checks using `FIRST/NEXT/LAST`.

Comment: I agree. Your solution is great. My intension was to point out the reason for the error without going to much into other practical considerations. I kept in mind that others will arrive at this page with the same error message under same circumstances and can easily understand what is the problem.

Comment: That's understandable; whereas [I answered the OP's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37724695/1509264) which had entirely been about why this occurs so had put that detail there.

Comment: Did not realize there was an earlier question. In this case it totally makes sense. Your solution is definitely better. Though I wonder whether how many million entries in the collection would make a looping over all entries slower than using `NEXT`. But it is also a matter of style and clean coding.

Answer (score 0):

What I've manage to do and seems to work is using an auxiliar table of objects, I iterate over the original array with the deleted item and then removing the gap in some auxiliar list and then assing this list back to the original array, something like this:

```
FOR i in 1..attributelist.COUNT+1 LOOP
      IF attributelist.EXISTS(i) THEN
        j := j+1;
        ls_attribute_list.EXTEND;
        ls_attribute_list(j) := attributelist(i);
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      attributelist := ls_attribute_list;
```

Comment: This will only work if you have deleted a single item (so `COUNT + 1 = LAST`). You would be better using `FOR i IN attributelist.FIRST .. attributelist.LAST LOOP`. Also, the `ELSE CONTINUE` is redundant since you are not doing anything after the loop.

Comment: You could also replace the entire lot with `attributelist := T_ATTRIBUTEPAGE_ATTRIBUTELIST() MULTISET UNION attributelist;` and that will compact the array.

Comment: so basically the `MULTISET UNION` will make the list dense?

Comment: [`MULTISET UNION`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/operators006.htm) will concatenate two collections (nested tables) - a side effect of the concatenation is that the resulting collection is dense.

Comment: can you update your answer with this so I can mark it as the soution please?

Comment: It is in my answer as part of the function for compacting collections but I'll try to make it clearer.